# Dot net date range validation not working

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am using textbox control having attribute/property CssClass="datepicker form-control". I am using range validator to validate date range

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass = "datepicker form-control"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Date must be greater than 01-01-1980 and less than equal to Current date. " ControlToValidate="txtDate" 
Type="Date" ValidationGroup="VGASumbit"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

I am setting range of RangeValidator2 control in Page_Load. See Below

```
 DateTime dtMinValue = new DateTime(1980, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0);
 RangeValidator2.MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
 RangeValidator2.MinimumValue = dtMinValue.ToShortDateString();
```

client system datetime setting is in format: 18-04-2023 i.e dd-mm-yyyy
server system datetime format is 4/18/2023 ie m/dd/yyyy

Due to this above validation not work correctly.

What need to be done so that validation correctly works.

[Screenshot of incorrect date range validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awiO5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

u can use [FluentValidation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/index.html)

```
RuleFor(x => x.DateOfBirth).GreaterThan(DateTime.MinValue);
```